# Using ScalaTest to test java that contain @Autowired and private fields

Tags: java, scala, mockito, private, scalatest

I have begun to use ScalaTest to test my Java code and I like it (I've read the "Testing in Scala" book).

Recently I've been trying to test some java Spring code that contain fields which are marked `private` and `@Autowired`.  There are no setter methods for these fields.

I realise that I could easily test them using JUnit + Mockito using the annotations `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock`, however, I would like to test them using ScalaTest and a mocking framework (such as Mockito or ScalaMock).

My question: Can Scalatest + Mockito be used to mock out private fields or do these frameworks require that my java classes have a `public` setter method defined for my `private` + `@Autowired` fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with InjectMocks.  Here's a working example using ScalaTest and Mockito to test a class containing @Autowired members:

```
import org.mockito.{MockitoAnnotations, InjectMocks, Mock}
import org.scalatest.{FunSpec, BeforeAndAfter}
import org.scalatest.Matchers._
import org.mockito.Mockito._
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired

class InjectMocksSpec extends FunSpec with BeforeAndAfter {

  @Mock
  var paramMock: MockedClass = null

  @InjectMocks
  var testClass = new TestClass()

  describe("InjectMocks") {
    it("should inject mock for Autowired field") {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

      when(paramMock.get).thenReturn("bar")

      testClass.test should be("bar")

      verify(paramMock, times(1)).get
    }
  }

}

class MockedClass {
  def get: String = {
    "foo"
  }
}

class TestClass {
  @Autowired
  var param: MockedClass = null

  def test: String = {
    param.get
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it's been far better to add setters to those autowired beans.  Otherwise, the only way you're going to inject the behavior you want is through a convoluted reflection process, which only serves to complicate matters.

To make it explicit that the setters aren't to be used outside of test, you can do a couple of things:

- Mark them as package-private

  ```
  void setDao(final Dao dao) {
      this.dao = dao;
  }
  ```
- Annotate them with [`@VisibleForTesting`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.html) from Guava

Alternatively, it may be a good time to revisit the autowiring scheme; it can become very unwieldy if you have a lot of beans that you're automatically wiring in.

Comment: Hi Makoto ... thanks for the quick reply.  Both bulleted suggestions are helpful and I will consider using them.

However, I'm specifically asking if any of the Mocking frameworks for Scala (e.g. ScalaMock or Mockito with MockitoSugar) will support testing of java code that contains private fields that are not accessible via public accessor methods.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Mock` annotation in `import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.Mock`

`@Mock 
 private var someDao:SomeDao =_`

this works but is not advisable to use. It is also being deprecated